# Why the ui text is never empty?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Method that create a ui text with a flag bool to decide if to display the text with some content or empty.

I used a break point and it's getting to the CreateText(false) line but the text is still exist it's not empty ""

I did that if the user use two finger it will display content in the text and if with one finger it should not show anything in the text.

```
private void CreateText(bool create)
    {
        Text text;

        // Load the Arial font from the Unity Resources folder.
        Font arial;
        arial = (Font)Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "LegacyRuntime.ttf");

        // Create Canvas GameObject.
        GameObject canvasGO = new GameObject();
        canvasGO.name = "Canvas";
        canvasGO.AddComponent<Canvas>();
        canvasGO.AddComponent<CanvasScaler>();
        canvasGO.AddComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();

        // Get canvas from the GameObject.
        Canvas canvas;
        canvas = canvasGO.GetComponent<Canvas>();
        canvas.renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay;

        // Create the Text GameObject.
        GameObject textGO = new GameObject();
        textGO.transform.parent = canvasGO.transform;
        textGO.AddComponent<Text>();

        // Set Text component properties.
        text = textGO.GetComponent<Text>();
        text.font = arial;
        if (create)
        {
            text.text = "Press space key";
        }
        else
        {
            text.text = "";
        }
        text.fontSize = 48;
        text.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;

        // Provide Text position and size using RectTransform.
        RectTransform rectTransform;
        rectTransform = text.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rectTransform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(600, 200);
    }
```

using it

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                move  = true;
                GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
                sphere.transform.position = hit.point;
                sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
                sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
                Destroy(sphere.GetComponent<Collider>());
            }
        }
        
        if(Input.touchCount == 2)
        {
            CreateText(true);
        }
        else
        {
            CreateText(false);
        }

        if(move)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, hit.point, Time.deltaTime * 2f);

            Vector3 direction = hit.point - transform.position;
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, rot, 100 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: text is a component while text.text is a string.

Comment: Your update method has no string checking in.  So has nothing to do with the contents of the text. Which means a decision to create is already made

Comment: I don't know why i messed it so hard.  In the end i just added a public Text text variable and added ui text in the inspector and then in the update just setting text.text to "some content"  or empty "" easier and working.